# How to send GET request including headers using python

Tags: python, api, curl, urllib2

I'm trying to build a website using web.py, which is able to search the mobile.de database (mobile.de is a German car sales website). For this I need to use the [mobile.de API](http://services.mobile.de/manual/index.html) and make a GET request to it doing the following (this is an example from [the API docs](http://services.mobile.de/manual/search-api.html)):

```
GET /1.0.0/ad/search?exteriorColor=BLACK&modificationTime.min=2012-05-04T18:13:51.0Z HTTP/1.0
Host: services.mobile.de
Authorization: QWxhZGluOnNlc2FtIG9wZW4=
Accept: application/xml
```

(The authorization needs to be my username and password joined together using a colon and then being encoded using Base64.)

So I use urllib2 to do the request as follows:

```
>>> import base64
>>> import urllib2
>>> headers = {'Authorization':  base64.b64encode('myusername:mypassw'), 'Accept': 'application/xml'}
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search?exteriorColor=BLACK', headers=headers)
```

And from here I am unsure how to proceed. req appears to be an instance with some methods to get the information in it. But did it actually send the request? And if so, where can I get the response?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `req.read()` to call the URL and get the response.

But you'd be better off using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, which is much easier to use.